# FastCGI: manager (pid YYYYY): server (pid XXXX) exited with status 13

Tags: apache-2.2, fastcgi, perl, cisco-catalyst

```
FastCGI: manager (pid 6776): server (pid 20254) exited with status 13
FastCGI: manager (pid 6776): server (pid 18918) started FastCGI:
server (pid 18918): initialized
```

I am getting above mentioned error on my catalyst based application running under Apache based FASTCGI server. Due to above error it is showing me "Internal Server Error" and in next subsequent call it start running normally.

I could not able to understand the behaviour.

Regards,

Hardik

Comment: What troubleshooting have you done?

Comment: Hi t1nt1n, Actually I could not able to find out where to start because I could not able to get any hint from apache error logs  or access logs.

Comment: I have solved the issue by migrating into **starman** instead of fastcgi.

Comment: To be fair that isn't a fix. It's just a different set of errors.